# Using dependency injection in an existing project

Tags: java, dependency-injection, cdi, jboss-weld

We have an old application which uses modules. The main entry point (`main()` method) instantiates modules (classes) with reflection based on an XML configuration file, like:

```
<modules>
    <module class="com.example.moduleone.ModuleOne" />
    <module class="com.example.moduletwo.ModuleTwo" />
<modules>
```

A few modules have additional configuration in the `modules.xml`, for example:

```
<modules>
    <module class="com.example.modulethree.ConfigurableModule">
        <config>
            <keyOne>valueOne</keyOne>
            <keyTwo>valueTwo</keyTwo>
    </module>
<modules>
```

These kind of modules has a parametrized constructor which accepts an `org.jdom.Element` instance (parsed from the XML file):

```
public ConfigurableModule(Element moduleConfig) {
    ...
}
```

We would like to use CDI/Weld (or something else) for dependency injection. How can we instantiate our modules with the DI framework?

Would it be easier with Spring or Guice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out the answer with clay's eye opener answer. (Thank you!)

First, a bean which loads the `modules.xml`:

```
import static com.google.common.collect.Lists.newArrayList;

import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.InjectionPoint;
import javax.inject.Singleton;

@Singleton
public class RequiredModuleConfigurationLoader {

    private final List<RequiredModuleConfiguration> configurationList = 
        newArrayList();

    public RequiredModuleConfigurationLoader() {
        // read the XML file here
        configurationList.add(new RequiredModuleConfiguration(
            "cdiproto.ModuleOne", "moduleConfig1"));
        configurationList.add(new RequiredModuleConfiguration(
            "cdiproto.ModuleTwo", "moduleConfig2"));
    }

    @Produces
    public List<RequiredModuleConfiguration> getRequiredModuleConfigurations() {
        return newArrayList(configurationList);
    }

    @Produces
    public ModuleConfiguration getModuleConfiguration(
            final InjectionPoint injectionPoint) {
        final String injectedClassName = injectionPoint.getMember()
            .getDeclaringClass().getName();
        for (final RequiredModuleConfiguration requiredModuleConfiguration: 
                configurationList) {
            final String moduleClassName = 
                requiredModuleConfiguration.getClassName();
            if (moduleClassName.equals(injectedClassName)) {
                final String option = 
                    requiredModuleConfiguration.getSubConfiguration();
                return new ModuleConfiguration(option);
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unknown module: " + 
            injectedClassName);
    }
}
```

It also produces the configuration instance for every module based on the `InjectionPoint`.

The Application class, which loads the modules based on the XML configuration is the following:

```
import static com.google.common.collect.Lists.newArrayList;

import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Any;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Instance;
import javax.enterprise.util.AnnotationLiteral;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Singleton;

@Singleton
public class Application {

    private final Annotation qualifiers = new AnnotationLiteral<Any>() { };

    @Inject
    private List<RequiredModuleConfiguration> requiredModuleConfigurationInstance;

    @Inject
    private Instance<Module> moduleInstance;

    private final List<Module> modules = newArrayList();

    public void init() throws Exception {
        for (final RequiredModuleConfiguration requiredModuleConfiguration: 
                requiredModuleConfigurationInstance) {
            final String className = requiredModuleConfiguration.getClassName();
            final Class<Module> moduleClass = 
                (Class<Module>) Class.forName(className);

            final Instance<Module> currentModuleInstance = 
                moduleInstance.select(moduleClass, qualifiers);
            final Module module = currentModuleInstance.get();
            modules.add(module);
        }
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

And a sample module:

```
import javax.inject.Inject;

public class ModuleOne implements Module {

    @Inject
    private ModuleConfiguration moduleConfiguration;

    @Inject
    ModuleTwo moduleTwo;

    public String getName() {
        return "moduleOne name";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using Spring or Guice would make this much easier. There you can create an object in the configuration file, and inject that very object into another object during configuration.

The concept will look similar to what you have, but much better as you won't have to redesign from scratch **and** find all the nuances of DI.

An example from [the Sping docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.3/reference/beans.html)

```
  <!-- setter injection using the nested <ref/> element -->
  <property name="beanOne"><ref bean="anotherExampleBean"/></property>

  <!-- setter injection using the neater 'ref' attribute -->
  <property name="beanTwo" ref="yetAnotherBean"/>
  <property name="integerProperty" value="1"/>
</bean>

<bean id="anotherExampleBean" class="examples.AnotherBean"/>
<bean id="yetAnotherBean" class="examples.YetAnotherBean"/>
```

The classes are called `bean`s and an instance of one ("anotherExampleBean") is injected into another ("exampleBean"). (This example is using setter-injection, but you could also use constructor-injection so you don't have to re-write all your classes, if that helps)

Comment: I'm not sure this really addresses the tricky part of the OP's question, which is that some of his classes are fed *parts* of the parse tree of the main configuration file during their creation.  As far as I know, you can't do that with spring, so he'll have to rework anyway.

Comment: I didn't read that from the question. The question's "module XML" config approach sounds very similar to a spring config file, which can also import other spring config files. Based on the description, I don't think they would have to change their classes much at all, simply re-write the configurations. (At least from what I can tell in the question).

Comment: @clay: Thanks for idea, it was a real eye opener. (I'd upvote your answer it if I could.)